# Inconsistent timeout errors on nginx server

Tags: nginx, timeout, reverse-proxy

I have an application that is trying to make ajax requests from a Javascript application to retrieve xml files from an nginx server. Normally everything is fine but I often see errors in the nginx log (and get errors from my applications error reporting) that nginx expriences a timeout during the get:

```
2015/11/16 21:15:21 [error] 1208#0: *4894044 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 209.95.138.54, server: www.servername.com, request: "GET /Shape%20Textures/Metal/Born%20to%20Shine.jpg?agentView=436314 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/AQO/Shape%20Textures/Metal/Born%20to%20Shine.jpg?agentView=436314", host: "www.servername.com.com", referrer: "https://www.servername.com.com/?nid=39956&mode=edit"
```

We also sometimes get this similar error:

```
2015/11/17 19:03:16 [error] 1002#0: *54042 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 137.164.121.52, server: www.servername.com, request: "POST /projects/?q=node/36375/update_project_time_and_stats HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/projects/?q=node/36375/update_project_time_and_stats", host: "www.servername.com", referrer: "https://www.servername.com/AQO/?nid=36375&mode=edit"
```

I have seem similar posts with similar timeouts but all of those posts seemed reproducible. This issue never happens to me but running on the live server I will see 5-30 of these timeouts a day.

Here is my nginx config:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;

server {
    server_name servername.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.servername.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/star_servername_com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/star_servername_com.key;

    # Redirect all non-SSL traffic to SSL.
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
      rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name www.servername.com;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_read_timeout 120s;
    }
}
```

Since I can't reproduce it I wonder how might I be able to track down this issue?

Comment: Check your upstream server log?

Comment: I've never heard of the upstream server log and didn't find much with a Google search, is this something that you can enable through nginx?

Comment: I'm referring to the 127.0.0.1:3000 server log.

Comment: There is a node.js server running on port 3000. Nothing in there related to the timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to
>   upstream

means that your upstream server didn't accept connection in time

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response
>   header from upstream

means that your upstream server didn't respond with answer in time

So check your upstream server at 127.0.0.1:3000. It may have setup with small number of incoming connections or some sort of DDoS protection or really heavy loaded at the moment or something else.

Comment: There is a node.js server running on port 3000 but as far as I can tell node.js doesn't put any limits on incoming connections. Ubuntu has a default incoming connections of 1024 shown by ulimit -n

Comment: if your Node.js server is heavy loaded or run really long tasks you can try to encrease nginx's [proxy_connect_timeout](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout) and [proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout). Their default values are 60 seconds and you may need to increase this settings

Answer (score 1):

I would like to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678783/1315093) which shows how to optimize your settings.

Although not the best solution, but very dependent on what you'd like to achieve, you could simply increase `proxy_read_timeout` to for example `300`.