# PHP and MySQL application working in Apache but not in NGINX

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I have developed a PHP + MySQL application that compares two tables in a database looking for differences and registering them in another table.

This code is running ok on Apache webservers. It tooks about 20 seconds to compare about 50.000 rows, and it gets the results.

But my client is running his server on NGINX and it's impossible to get the code working. It gives a 500 error and this logs:

> 2016/08/24 13:51:27 [error] 27176#0: *111657 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 79.147.146.205

We tried to change `mysql.connect_timeout` and `php fastcgi_read_timeout`. But it's still not working!!

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NGINX: upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740635/nginx-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-out-while-reading-response-hea)