# R Plumber API: Prevent "504 Gateway Time-out"

Tags: r, nginx, timeout, http-status-code-504, plumber

I have written and deployed an R API using [plumber](https://plumber.trestletech.com/) to a Digital Ocean droplet as in the [instructions](https://plumber.trestletech.com/docs/digitalocean/).

I am posting in .json data and expecting .json data back. To do this I use the `curl` command from the command line, for example:

```
curl --data @data/data.json http://[API ADDRESS] > results/output.json
```

This works fine when I post a small dataset but as the dataset gets bigger I start to get an HTTP error as follows:

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried editing `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to allows for longer timeouts and larger files but still no luck. The `nginx.conf` file is as follows:

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 3000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

        ##
        # Allow for longer jobs
        ##

        client_header_timeout 3000;
        client_body_timeout 3000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

I then restart the nginx server with `sudo service nginx restart` but still get the timeout error.

The `/var/log/nginx/error.log` line reads as follows:

```
*4 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: [MY IP], server: _, request: "POST [API]", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/[API]", host: "[HOST ADDRESS]"
```

Any help or tips you can give on how plumber works under the hood would be very useful indeed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed this now by adding the following lines to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/[my site]/mysite.conf`

```
location {
    # time out settings
    proxy_connect_timeout 3000s;
    proxy_send_timeout   3000;
    proxy_read_timeout   3000;
}
```

I also commented out the `keepalive_timout` flag in `nginx.conf` and specified the http version as in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740635/nginx-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-out-while-reading-response-hea#36589180) but I am not sure exactly what made the difference. If I find out I will update the answer.