# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn

I'm trying to host django 1.11 application on ubuntu 16.4 server using Nginx. 
But After running the server I'm getting `504 Gateway Time-out`

here is my all port log

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3209/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15218/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1204/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      28810/java
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      28810/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1204/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           963/dhclient
```

```html
command=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/ok/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --limit-request-line 8000 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/app/socks/ok.sock configuration.wsgi:application
directory=/home/ubuntu/app/onekkom/backend
user=ubuntu
group=www-data
chmod=664
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/ok_prod_gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/ok_prod_gunicorn.out.log
```

Nginx error.log

> *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: 118.179.95.25, server:
>   18.136.204.142, requ$
>
> 2019/07/24 18:13:13 [error] 15221#15221: *1 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 118.179.95.25, server: 18.136.204.142, requ$
>
> 2019/07/24 18:20:17 [error] 15485#15485: *1 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 118.179.95.25, server: 18.136.204.142, requ$

any one have any idea about this issue? any sort of help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740635/nginx-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-out-while-reading-response-hea

Comment: I've tried all of given solution but it won't work , Possible reason its django project and the link you gave that is php application

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn times out after 30 seconds by default. It is most likely a gunicorn timeout, and not an nginx timeout. You can increase the timeout in the gunicorn settings. Generally, you may want to do something about the request that is taking over 30 seconds.

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html

Comment: add `--timeout INT` where `INT` is the number of seconds

Comment: /home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 4 --timeout INT 30 --limit-request-line 8000 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/onekkom/app.sock backend.configuration.wsgi:application 
here is it , but its not working

Comment: Just use `--timeout 120`, `INT` is meant to be replaced by the number in that case. Also, 30 is the default, so setting it to 30 will not do anything useful.

Comment: after adding '--timeout 120' its showing 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196955/discussion-between-zahid-uan-nabi-and-sam-creamer).

Comment: Try giving nginx and gunicorn the same timeout window. There's a breakdown in communication between the two. Also, why does the request take so long?

Comment: I'm booting celery and webapp at the same time with gunicorn, may be that's why.