# Nginx ingress: upstream connection timeout (Operation timed out)

Tags: sockets, nginx, udp

I have configured nginx-ingress for UDP load balancing. Below is my configuration in helm chart.

```
udp: {
       "514":"default/syslog-service:514",
       "162":"default/trapreceiver-service:162",
       "123":"default/ntp-service:123"
}
```

And my configmap

```
data:
  max-worker-connections: "65535"
  proxy-body-size: 500m
  proxy-connect-timeout: "50"
  proxy-next-upstream-tries: "2"
  proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
  proxy-send-timeout: "120"
```

Ingress is not able to send UDP packets to backend due to below error

```
[1000::601] [09/Nov/2020:17:19:57 +0000] UDP 502 0 48 600.000
[1000::601] [09/Nov/2020:17:19:57 +0000] UDP 502 0 48 600.001
2020/11/09 17:19:57 [error] 1166#1166: *868219 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while proxying connection, udp client: 1000::601, server: [::]:123, upstream: "[fc00::fcc1]:123", bytes from/to client:48/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/48
[1000::601] [09/Nov/2020:17:19:57 +0000] UDP 502 0 387 600.001
2020/11/09 17:19:57 [error] 1166#1166: *868221 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while proxying connection, udp client: 1000::601, server: [::]:162, upstream: "[fc00::696e]:162", bytes from/to client:387/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/387
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm curious about the solution.

Comment: I am facing this issue as well but unable to find answer anywhere as of now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NGINX: upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740635/nginx-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-out-while-reading-response-hea)